# Stuck in a express callback hell

Tags: node.js, express, callback, promise, nodemailer

I can't cancel the request after sending the email successfully. How can I return properly after sending the email? This might be a callback hell, but I cant figure out how to solve it.

I tried to put some return in different parts but it didn't work.

```
const router        = require('express').Router();
const nodemailer    = require('nodemailer');
const emailExistence= require('email-existence');

module.exports = router;

// Send email when user has forgotten his/her password
router.post('/forgetPass', (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.body.email){
        next(new Error("Email is required."));
        return;
    }

    emailExistence.check(req.body.email, function(err,res){

        if(err || !res){
            next(new Error("The email does'nt exist."));
            return;
        }else{
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
                    pass: 'mypassword'
                }
            });

            let mailOptions = {
                from:       'myemail@gmail.com',
                to:          req.body.email,
                subject:    'Link for setting a new password',
                html:       'Set a new password'
                text:       'email text'    
            };


            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                if (error) {
                    next(new Error("Error in sending email."));
                    return;
                }

                res.json(Object.assign(req.base, {
                    message: "The email has been sent successfully.",
                    data: info
                }));
                return;

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what you do in  `emailExistence.check` its  a db check??

Comment: @iam-batman, It checks if the email exists or not (res is true when email does exist [means the email is valid], res is false when the email doesn't exist). That works properly, and I get the error when the email doesn't exist. but the problem is when the email has been sent successfully. the request doesn't end there.

Comment: can you able to log the `info` after sending mail

Comment: @iam-batman, no, It doesn't return the json. I tried return res.json(Object.assign...  too. but it still doesn't work

Comment: I mean this ` transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){console.log(info)}`

Comment: I had sent email for myself and I received the email. so it works well. I logged the info, this is it (I changed the addresses):     </br>     { accepted: [ 'myemail@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK some numbers - gsmtp',
  envelope:
   { from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
     to: [ 'myemail@gmail.com' ] },
  messageId: '<some numbers@gmail.com>' }

Answer (score 2):

Once you set your response field on successful sending, call next() as a last step, so the next middleware gets the request and sends the response back. So basically:

```
...
res.json(yourResponse);
next();
...
```

Or, if this is the last middleware, send the response back to client:

```
res.send(yourResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way. The emailExistence didn't let me to use promises, so I used email-ckeck instead of it:

```
const router        = require('express').Router();
const nodemailer    = require('nodemailer');
const emailExistence= require('email-existence');
var emailCheck      = require('email-check');

module.exports = router;

router.post('/forgetPass', (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.body.email){
        next(new Error("Email is required."));
        return;
    }

    // Check the req.body.email with email pattern regex
    var patt = new RegExp (process.env.EMAIL_PATTERN__REGEX),
        isEmail = patt.test(req.body.email);    

    if(!isEmail){
        next(new Error("The email does'nt seem to be a valid email. If you are sure about your email validity contact the website admin."));
        return;
    } 

    return emailCheck(req.body.email)
        .then(function(result){
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL,
                    pass: process.env.EMAILPASSWORD
                }
            });

            let mailOptions = {
                from:       process.env.EMAIL,
                to:         req.body.email,
                subject:    'Link for setting a new password',
                html:       'Set a new password from <a href="http://www.example.com/newpass">this link</a>.'    
            };

            return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
                .then(function (result2) {
                            res.status(200).json(Object.assign(req.base, {
                                message: "The email has been sent successfully.",
                                data: null
                            }));
                            return;
                        },
                        function(error2){
                            next(new Error("Error in sending email."));
                                return;
                        });
        },
        function(error) {
            next(new Error("The email does'nt seem to be a valid email. If you are sure about your email validity contact the website admin."));
            return;
        });
});
```